# Equality operator (==) unsupported on map iterators for non-copyable maps

Tags: c++, c++11

When I have a map of non-copyable objects, why can't I compare the iterators using ==? I would imagine it does not need to copy (or move) the actual objects when doing equality testing on the iterators.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class A {
private:
    int i;
public:
    A(int i) : i(i) {}
    A(A&) = delete;
    A(A&& a) : i(a.i) {}
    ~A() {}
    A& operator=(A&) = delete;

    bool operator==(const A& a) const { return i == a.i; }
};

int main() {
    map<int, A> myMap;

    map<int, A>::iterator it = myMap.find(1);
    cout << (it == myMap.end()) << endl;
}
```

This example fails to compile, giving an error on the line with the `cout`.

g++ gives this error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘struct std::pair<const int, A>’:
test2.cpp:24:27:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_pair.h:127:17: error: ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const int; _T2 = A]’ declared to take     const reference, but implicit declaration would take non-const
   constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;
```

clang++ gives this error:

```
/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_pair.h:127:17: error: the parameter for this explicitly-defaulted copy constructor is const, but a member or base requires it to be non-const
      constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;
                ^
test2.cpp:24:14: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::pair<const int, A>' requested here
        cout << (it == myMap.end()) << endl;
```

However, it does work if a `map<int, int>` is used instead of a `map<int, A>`. Using a `const map<int, A>` with `map<int, A>::const_iterator` does not help.

I tried looking up the exact signature of map::iterator::operator== on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator), (map::iterator is a BidirectionalIterator, which is a ForwardIterator, which is an InputIterator) but the website is vague about the exact type signatures in the concepts.

Comment: Does this happen if you compare it to things other than `myMap.end()`?

Comment: Also, it's a lot cleaner to simply make the copy constructor and assignment operator private to make something non-copyable, vs. exposing them as public methods that don't actually work.

Comment: @aruisdante: I don't seem to be able to compare it to `myMap.begin()`, or perform other operations on it either (e.g. `it->first`). Rather than exposing them as public methods that "don't work", i'm using [deleted functions](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#default)

Comment: Doh, silly `c++ 11` tag.

Comment: @Datalore If you are interested, here is why you got the weird error message: [Comparing two map::iterators: why does it need the copy constructor of std::pair?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22357887/341970) The answer is totally non-trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your deleted methods to make A noncopyable ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class A {
private:
    int i;
public:
    A(int i) : i(i) {}
    // A(A&) = delete; should be ...
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&& a) : i(a.i) {}
    ~A() {}
    // A& operator=(A&) = delete; should be ...
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;

    bool operator==(const A& a) const { return i == a.i; }
};

int main() {
    map<int, A> myMap;

    map<int, A>::iterator it = myMap.find(1);
    cout << (it == myMap.end()) << endl;
}
```

Verified this with gcc/g++ 4.6.3

Removing the "const" from the copy constructor and the assignment operator caused my compiler to give the same error which you received.

I would have to look up the details/references as to why those are declared that way, but the copy constructor and the assignment operator always take a const reference (make sense as the value to which your instance is being assigned should not be modified by the method).

Comment: Huh, good catch, I still don't understand why the signatures of deleted functions affect the other operations of the class.

Comment: IIRC, it has something to do with the methods that are generated by default by the compiler. Copy constructor and assignment are two of them, and if your method signature doesn't match what the compiler is expecting to see, it is not an actual replacement of the compiler-generated methods.

Comment: In other words, what you think you are `delete`-ing is not actually getting deleted.